# make join if value is null set as default in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i need help from your side:

I have two tables t1 and t2 having below data:

TABLE t1

```
ID  PROP_ID County_code prop_type
1   abc     IE          A
2   bcd     US          P
3   cde     CA          P
4   def     IND         P
5   efg     CHINA       P
```

table T2

```
ID  PROP_IND    PROD_ID Amount
10  A                   200
20  P           US      300
30  P           CA      400
40  P           IND     500
50  P           CHINA   600
60  P           700
```

in table t2 1 prop_id is `null` for Prop_ind A and  one for prop_id p.

I am making a join between these two tables like below:

```
decode(t1.prop_type,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.country_code) = 
NVL(t2.prop_id, decode(t2.prop_ind,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.country_code))
```

But this join gives me incorrect result. As `null` prop_id  for prop_ind A and P in table t2 are default values.

```
select * 
from t1,t2 
where decode(t1.prop_type,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.county_code) = NVL(t2.prop_id, decode(t2.prop_ind,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.county_code))
```

this query gives me 9 records however i am looking only 5 records –  user2862073 7 mins ago

output came in as:

```
ID  PROP_ID COUNTY_CODE PROP_TYPE   ID  PROP_IND    PROP_ID AMOUNT 
3   cde CA  P   60  P   -   700 
3   cde CA  P   30  P   CA  400 
5   efg CHINA   P   50  P   CHINA   600 
5   efg CHINA   P   60  P   -   700 
1 abc   IE  A   10  A   -   200 
4   def IND P   40  P   IND 500 
4   def IND P   60  P   -   700 
2   bcd US  P   60  P   -   700 
2   bcd US  P 20    P   US  300
```

however i am looking only 5 records and it should be

```
ID  PROP_ID County_code prop_type   Amount 
1   abc IE  A   200 
2   bcd US  P   300 
3   cde CA  P   400 
4   def IND P   500 
5   efg CHINA   P   600
```

Please suggest me how to make join on this in correct way.

Comment: Please show the result you are getting and what you want instead.

Comment: for prop_IND A its shows correct output but for P its showing duplicate records.1 for exsting county and one for prop_IND is P with null. please assist

Comment: Please show (add to your question) the result of your query and the desired result. You may want to post your entire SQL code as well.

Comment: And *entire SQL code* also consists of the `create table` and `insert` statements, of course.

Comment: query is :  select *  from t1,t2
where decode(t1.prop_type,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.county_code) = 
NVL(t2.prop_id, decode(t2.prop_ind,'A',t1.prop_id,'P',t1.county_code))                             this query gives me 9 records however i am looking only 5 records

Comment: output came in as:  ID PROP_ID COUNTY_CODE PROP_TYPE ID PROP_IND PROP_ID AMOUNT
3 cde CA P 60 P - 700
3 cde CA P 30 P CA 400
5 efg CHINA P 50 P CHINA 600
5 efg CHINA P 60 P - 700
1 abc IE A 10 A - 200
4 def IND P 40 P IND 500
4 def IND P 60 P - 700
2 bcd US P 60 P - 700
2 bcd US P 20 P US 300

Comment: however i am looking only 5 records and it should be ID PROP_ID County_code prop_type Amount
1 abc IE A 200
2 bcd US P 300
3 cde CA P 400
4 def IND P 500
5 efg CHINA P 600

Comment: code for table creation:create table t2
(ID number,PROP_IND varchar2(10),PROP_ID varchar2(10),Amount varchar2(3));   create table t1
(ID number,PROP_ID varchar2(10),County_code varchar2(10),prop_type varchar2(3));

Comment: René Nyffenegger any suggestion..please assist

Comment: @user2862073, it is better that you edit the question and add details there instead of providing information in comments because people will miss to read your comments

Answer (score 0):

This is bound to happen.

For example:

```
select  Decode(t1.prop_type, 'A', t1.prop_id, 
                            'P', t1.county_code) from t1;
```

Gives you

```
abc
US
CA
IND
CHINA
```

Whereas

```
select  Nvl(t2.prop_id, 
Decode(t2.prop_ind, 'A', t1.prop_id, 
                    'P', t1.county_code)) from t1,t2;
```

And this gives you

```
abc
US
CA
IND
CHINA
IE
bcd
US
CA
IND
CHINA
US
cde
US
CA
IND
CHINA
CA
def
US
CA
IND
CHINA
IND
efg
US
CA
IND
CHINA
CHINA
```

Since there is no unique column to be joined in t1 and t2, it goes on for a cartesian join on 6*5 = 30 rows. So the last row in T2 will not be able to find one single match in T1.

Hence when you run

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.prop_id, 
       t1.county_code, 
       t1.prop_type, 
       t2.amount 
FROM   t1, 
       t2 
WHERE  Decode(t1.prop_type, 'A', t1.prop_id, 
                            'P', t1.county_code) = Nvl(t2.prop_id, 
Decode(t2.prop_ind, 'A', t1.prop_id, 
                    'P', t1.county_code)) ;
```

you get

```
ID  PROP_ID COUNTY_CODE PROP_TYPE   AMOUNT
1   abc IE  A   200
2   bcd US  P   300
2   bcd US  P   700
3   cde CA  P   400
3   cde CA  P   700
4   def IND P   500
4   def IND P   700
5   efg CHINA   P   600
5   efg CHINA   P   700
```

May be this would do

If you want to avoid hardcoding, then you need to select the decode options from a inline query

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.prop_id, 
       t1.county_code, 
       t1.prop_type,
       nvl (t2.amount,decode(t1.prop_type,'A',200,'P',700))
       from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.prop_type = t2.PROP_IND
       and t1.County_code = t2.prop_id
       order by t1.id;
```

Comment: this is my concern: id 2,,3,4,5 coming duplicate.i just want if county_code or prop_id defined in table t2 it will pick that amount other wise default.i am looking output as ID PROP_ID County_code prop_type Amount
1 abc IE A 200
2 bcd US P 300
3 cde CA P 400
4 def IND P 500
5 efg CHINA P 600   Amount for prop_ID abc came as 200 because its a default valaue for 'A' .similary if county code not found in t2 then it will pick default amount 700. my record count should same as t1 record count

Comment: I am looking for coorect join condition between table t1 and t2

Comment: you need to have a 1 to 1 mapping on your selection window between t1 and t2. Can we join ID number on t1 and t2?

Comment: No ,we can't  join iD,it will join t1.prop_ID to t2.prop_id FOR t2.PROP_IND 'A'   and it will join t1.county_code to t2.prop_id for t2.PROP_IND 'P' .it has  1 entry for default entry for 'A' and 1 default entry for 'P'.if the prop_id(for A) or county_code (for P) not available in t2 it will pick default value.for example...prop_id abc( IND A) has not found in t2 then its pick default amount 200. and for country code US,CA,INS,CHINA has defined in t2 than it will pick corresponding amount from t2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.prop_id, t1.county_code, t1.prop_type, t2.amount 
  from t1 join t2
    on (t1.prop_type = 'A' and t2.prop_ind='A' and t2.prod_id is null) 
    or (t1.prop_type = 'P' and t1.county_code = t2.prod_id)
```

Output:

```
        ID PROP_ID COUNTY_CODE PROP_TYPE     AMOUNT
---------- ------- ----------- --------- ----------
         1 abc     IE          A                200 
         2 bcd     US          P                300 
         3 cde     CA          P                400 
         4 def     IND         P                500 
         5 efg     CHINA       P                600
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6ed31/17)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID,  PROP_ID, County_code, prop_type ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'abc', 'IE', 'A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'bcd', 'US', 'P' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'cde', 'CA', 'P' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'def', 'IND', 'P' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'efg', 'CHINA', 'P' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t2 ( ID,  PROP_IND,    PROD_ID, Amount ) AS
          SELECT 10, 'A', NULL, '200' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20, 'P', 'US', '300' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 30, 'P', 'CA', '400' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 40, 'P', 'IND', '500' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 50, 'P', 'CHINA', '600' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 60, 'P', NULL, '700' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.*, t2.AMOUNT 
from t1 INNER JOIN t2
     ON (    t1.PROP_TYPE = t2.PROP_IND
         AND (    ( t1.PROP_TYPE = 'P' AND t1.County_Code = t2.prod_id )
              OR  ( t1.PROP_TYPE = 'A' AND (t1.PROP_ID = t2.PROD_ID OR t2.PROD_ID IS NULL ) )
             )
        )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6ed31/17/0)**:

```
| ID | PROP_ID | COUNTY_CODE | PROP_TYPE | AMOUNT |
|----|---------|-------------|-----------|--------|
|  1 |     abc |          IE |         A |    200 |
|  2 |     bcd |          US |         P |    300 |
|  3 |     cde |          CA |         P |    400 |
|  4 |     def |         IND |         P |    500 |
|  5 |     efg |       CHINA |         P |    600 |
```